# Magento 2 Option Payment Action: Authorize and Capture of Payment Authorize.Net doesn't work

Tags: magento2, payment, authorize.net, magento2.3.5

I try to configure Authorize and Capture for Payment Action.

[image]

But when I try to checkout with Authorize.Net payment, it still show Transaction Type: Authorization Only
[image]

I expect it to show Transaction Type is Authorize and Capture and auto-create invoice.

But now, I still create it by manual in the [image]backend of Magento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that version there is a bug in default config for authorize net which causes configuration for scope **Main Website** to be unchecked by default and it's set to authorize only.

[image]

You can either set desired option in that scope and save or just check **Use Default** and that should solve it.

Comment: Great help! Thank you so much!